# openlayers - how to render vector layer in openlayers with WebGl

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I was used [this tutorial](https://dev.camptocamp.com/files/gberaudo/webgl_polygons_lines/examples/vector-layer.html?renderer=webgl&mode=raw) and copy code of tutorial step by step but don't work for me.

As mentioned in the tutorial, I was used `?renderer=webgl` as a query string.

here is `jsfiddle` of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/4gvdsjwj/

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the 'renderer' option in your map definition.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
layers: [layer],
renderer: 'webgl',
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2
})
```

});